# How to merge some files using mapreduce?

Tags: java, file-io, merge, hadoop, mapreduce

I am going to merge some small files which under the same dir using map/reduce.I saw someone say using streaming will be very simple,but now I can only use the JAVA map/reduce.
   Now my solution is reading the files one record by one record and write them into the same output file.But I think it's inefficient.Can I use the whole file's content as mapper's value so I can improve the I/O efficiency?
   Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Does the order of merge matter to you? Are these file output from a previous MR job and you want to create a single sorted output, or do you just want a single file, with undefined ordering?

Comment: And are the files already in HDFS, or on some local disk?

Comment: I don't require the order,and all files are in HDFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "inefficient" way of doing this is to just cat the files and write it back out:

```
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/files/*.txt | hadoop fs -put - /output/path/blobbed.txt
```

You may find that this will work just fine with even larger data sets.

Comment: It is not inefficient, but slower than doing it in parallel by a mapreduce job. Depending on how many small files there are, it may be faster than a MR job though.

Comment: Do you think `getmerge`, then pushing the result back up wild be faster?

Comment: It depends on the sizes and how many of the files there are. But up to ~64m per file getmerge should be faster.

Comment: I have tried "getmerge&&put" to do the job,but our job will run on a distributed Hadoop more than 100 nodes.And my input may be more than 100 files.I think use map/reduce will improve the effiency.Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @wanghao, if you think about it, a MapReduce job will have to load the data, then send all of the data to the reducer. This is effectively the same thing but less overhead.